# Continuous Regression in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, non-linear-regression

Suppose we have a set of inputs (named x1, x2, ..., xn) that give us the output y. The goal is to predict y from some values of x1... xn that were not seem yet. It's clear to me that this problem can be modelled as a Regression problem on the realm of Machine Learning.

However, let's say data keep coming. I'm able to predict y from x1... xn. Furthermore, I'm able to check afterwards whether or not that prediction was a good one. If it was a good one, everything is fine. On the other hand, I would like to update my model in case that prediction deviates a lot from the real y. The one way I can see this is to insert this new data on my training set and train the regression algorithm again. Two problems arise from that. First, it may cost more than I can afford to recompute my module from scratch from time to time. Second, I may already have too much data on my training set so that new coming data is negligible. However, the new coming data might be more import than the older ones due to the nature of my problem.

It seems that a good solution would be to compute a kind of continuous regression that is more related to the new data than to the older one. I have searched for such approach but I have not found anything relevant. Perhaps I'm looking at the wrong direction. Does anyone have a clue on how to do it?

Comment: Isn't that just using sample-weights (probably supported in many [libs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit))?

Comment: Would that not fall in the "cost more than I can afford to recompute my module from scratch from time to time" category?

Comment: Depends on *what model* you solve, *how you solve it* and *what kind of data sizes* you process, important info not given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to consider the newer data more important you have to use weights. Usually it is called

> sample_weight

in fit() function in scikit-learn (if you use this library).

Weights can be defined as 1 / (time pass from this current observation).

Now about the second problem. If the recalculation takes much time you can cut your observations and use the latest ones. Fit your model on the whole data and on the fresh one + some part of the old data and check how much your weights are changed. I suppose if you really have a dependence between {x_i} and {y} you don't need the whole dataset.

Otherwise you can use weights again. But for now you will weight weights in the model:

> model for old data: w1*x1 + w2*x2 + ...
>
> model for new data: ~w1*x1 + ~w2*x2 + ...
>
> common model: (w1*a1_1 + ~w1*a1_2)*x1 + (w2*a2_1 + ~w2*a2_2)*x2 + ...

Here a1_1, a2_1 are the weights for 'old model', a2_1, a2_2 - for new one, w1, w2 - coefficients of old model, ~w1, ~w2 - of the new one.

Parameters {a} can be estimated as in the first bullet (be hands), but you also can create another linear model to estimate them. But my advice: don't use non-linear regression for {a} - you will overfit.